# Assign indicator to identify corresponding events in two variables

Tags: r, database, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
var_1 <- c(0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0)
var_2 <- c(F, F, F, F, F, F, T, T, T, F, F, F, T, T, T, F)
dat <- data.frame(var_1, var_2)
```

`var_1` indicates streak length. `var_2` indicates presence or absence of an event.

I want a logical variable which is `TRUE` for the first observation where `var_1` is 0 if the preceding streak for `var_1` is >=3 and any of the observations of `var_2` (that are >=3 for `var_1`) are `TRUE`. For example:

```
new_var <- c(F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T, F, F, F, F, T)
dat <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, new_var)
```

Please let me know if this isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `rle` from `base R` or `rleid` from `data.table` to create a group ('grp'), get the number of observations (`n()`) by group, while checking for `any` logical TRUE in 'var_2', `ungroup`, get the `lag` of 'any_t', create the 'new_var' after grouping by 'grp' by checking for `any` TRUE in 'any_t' and where `n >=3`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
tmp <- dat %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(var_1), var_1) %>% 
  summarise( any_t = any(var_2) & n() >=3, .groups = 'drop') %>%   
  mutate(any_t = lag(any_t))
 dat %>%
    group_by(grp = rleid(var_1)) %>%
   left_join(tmp) %>% 
   mutate(new_var2 = !duplicated(any_t) & any(any_t, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   mutate(any_t = NULL, grp = NULL)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 3
   var_1 var_2 new_var2
   <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>   
 1     0 FALSE FALSE   
 2     0 FALSE FALSE   
 3     2 FALSE FALSE   
 4     2 FALSE FALSE   
 5     0 FALSE FALSE   
 6     5 FALSE FALSE   
 7     5 TRUE  FALSE   
 8     5 TRUE  FALSE   
 9     5 TRUE  FALSE   
10     5 FALSE FALSE   
11     0 FALSE TRUE    
12     0 FALSE FALSE   
13     3 TRUE  FALSE   
14     3 TRUE  FALSE   
15     3 TRUE  FALSE   
16     0 FALSE TRUE
```